# Editing some tags when using XSLTcopy

Tags: templates, xslt, copy, match

Assume the following example XML :

```
  <tag>
    <subtag1>value1</subtag1>
    <subtag2>value2</subtag2>
    <subtag3>value3</subtag3>
    <subtag4>value4</subtag4>
    <subtag5>value5</subtg5>
  </tag>
```

and I would like to get all the tag section, but make some changes, like:

```
  <tag>
    <subtag1>value1</subtag1>
    <subtag2>value2</subtag2>
    <subtag3>value3</subtag3>
    <new-subtag4>value4</new-subtag4>
    <new-subtag5 type="new">value5</new-subtg5>
  </tag>
```

I tried the following script, but the result is not correct.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="parent::subtag4">
  <xsl:element name="new-subtag4">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="parent::subtag5">
  <xsl:element name="new-subtag5" type="n">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT that outputs the desired result is the following. It incorporates only two minor modifications concerning the attribute and the removal of the `parent::` prefixes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="subtag4">
  <xsl:element name="new-subtag4">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="subtag5">
  <xsl:element name="new-subtag5">
   <xsl:attribute name="type">new</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks. both of answers are true(the same). I just marked the first answer as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

`parent::subtag4` is not a valid match pattern. And you cannot add an attribute to `xsl:element` like that. Nor do you need to use `xsl:element` when the element's name is known.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subtag4">
    <new-subtag4>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </new-subtag4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subtag5">
    <new-subtag5 type="new">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </new-subtag5>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks. both of answers are true(the same). I just marked the first answer as right answer.